# Can you trigger a specific lsp code action programmicaly?

Tags: lua, lsp

Doing the equivalent of

```
:lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()
```

And pressing a key.

I tried some variants
like

```
:lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()
:sleep 5
:call feedkeys('4','t')
```

doesn't seem to work.